# Scanning all rows from DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

I have a `DataGrid` and I'm trying to scan all of the rows.

If I scan a `Datagrid` with max 30 rows, it works. But if there are more than 30 rows (i.e., `rows.Count > 30`), the it doesn't seem to work. It throws an `System.NullReferenceException`.

How can I scroll through `DataGrid` with more than 30 rows?

Comment: Define `scan` please as well as please show the code you are having issues with. `System.NullReferenceException` is a pretty common error as well and with out code, we can't help you find the main issue...

Comment: If you clarify more your question, giving an example of the code, it would make easy to help you, so, try editing your post with more clarifying information, cheers.       https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you mean iterate the data then you're best off iterating the bound data rather than trying to work with the ui which will virtualise everything you don't have visible. Also way easier to get at the data that way.

Comment: I want to loop all checkbox column into my datagrid to see if checkbox is checked or not; but after 30 loop the system return  System.NullReferenceException.  below insert xaml code and c# code

Answer (score 0):

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="2" Margin="5" CanUserAddRows ="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" x:Name="DTG_Can" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  CanUserDeleteRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionMode="Extended">
 <DataGrid.Columns>
  <DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
     <CheckBox Click="CheckUncheckAllCan_Click"/>
    </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
  </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="id" Binding="{Binding Path=id}" Visibility="Hidden"  IsReadOnly="True">
   <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
     <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
     <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
   </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
  </DataGridTextColumn>
....
```

C#

```
for (int i = 0; i < DTG_Can.Items.Count; i++)
{
 drv = (DataRowView)DTG_Can.Items.GetItemAt(i);
 var item = DTG_Can.Items[i];
 var CBM = DTG_Can.Columns[0].GetCellContent(item) as CheckBox;
 if (CBM.IsChecked == true && flagIns == 0) MessageBox.Show(i.ToString() + " - " + drv[2].ToString().ToUpper());
 else MessageBox.Show(i.ToString() + " - No Check");
```

I have another question for XAML. I use only one datagrid column for all datagridcheckbox or datagridtextcolum. Is better to use only one `<datagrid.columns>` or use foreach element one `<datagrid.columns>` ?